# how to know website supported languages?

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing a problem while doing localization testing using selenium web driver and java,**how to know the languages supported by a web page?**
**what i want to achieve is following**

```
 1. enter the URL for localization testing.
 2. i want to show web site supported languages to the User Automatically.
 3. Then depend upon user choosen language L10N/I18N process goes on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no 100% guaranteed way to do this, unfortunately, but the [rel="alternate" hreflang="foo"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) standard is probably your best bet to automated detection. If you want to be very fancy and thorough, though, you could attempt to fetch the page from different locations; you could also fetch the page using different values of the `Accept-Language` header; you could also try to modify the URL using common patterns that are known to be widely used for internationalizing domains (e.g. using "en.", "fr.", etc. prefixes in place of "www.", adding "/en/", "/fr/", etc. in the path, replacing the ".com" with ".co.uk", ".fr", ".de", etc.) in an attempt to find hidden international variants.

Since this is for automated testing, it may be easier if the user simply supplies the set of languages you want to test. Then, if the language is in hreflang, you use that URL; if it's not in hreflang, you use the original URL and simply specify that language in your `Accept-Language` header.